# Can't cross-compile gdb with MinGW

Tags: gdb, mingw, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross-compile gdb so I could debug my Windows version of program.
My host system is Arch Linux(5.13.4-arch1-1 to be exact).

I'm using MinGW from the official repositories.

```
$ i686-w64-mingw32-gcc --version
i686-w64-mingw32-gcc (GCC) 11.2.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I downloaded the source for gdb from https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/ (gdb-10.2.tar.gz).
I unpacked it, `cd` into dir and ran:

```
$ ./configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32
$ make
```

For long it compiled without any errors and then:

```
  CXX    source-cache.o
source-cache.c:37:10: fatal error: srchilite/sourcehighlight.h: No such file or directory
   37 | #include <srchilite/sourcehighlight.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

And also although compiler already compiled gdbserver and other different programs, I can't run them.
Launching `gdbserver.exe` with wine gives:

```
$ wine gdbserver.exe
0024:err:module:import_dll Library libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\udalny\\.local\\build\\gdb\\gdb-10.2\\gdbserver\\gdbserver.exe") not found
0024:err:module:import_dll Library libstdc++-6.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\udalny\\.local\\build\\gdb\\gdb-10.2\\gdbserver\\gdbserver.exe") not found
0024:err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Importing dlls for L"Z:\\home\\udalny\\.local\\build\\gdb\\gdb-10.2\\gdbserver\\gdbserver.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

Is it not statically linked?

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid the problem with the `configure` flag `--disable-source-highlight` if you can do without source highlighting.

Comment: I hope there is a better solution in the meanwhile?

Comment: Have you tried building source-highlight from source or installing your repo's dev package?